# Is it Possible to launch/Trigger an desktop bridged app(Win32) with/without command line parameter from windows task scheduler?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge, windows-task-scheduler

I have a WPF application which is converted to UWP using the desktop bridge, Now I need to call this app/exe from windows scheduler to do some stuff. Now my problem is getting **access denied**. If any app trying run from task scheduler getting this access denied error.[image]

Comment: Do you have an app execution alias (just a guess)? And is the task being launched from an account that has the app installed?

Comment: No alias now, Is it possible to trigger an exe under **C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.BingWeather_4.26.12153.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe** from task scheduler peter-torr-msft: @PeterTorr-MSFT

Comment: Are you trying to launch your app or the Bing Weather app?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I am trying to launch my own app from task scheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have identified a workaround to achieve this. My actual requirement was 'I need to trigger an action  in  my Desktop bridged UWP app from windows scheduler' unfortunately windows scheduler has not read/write access to the uwp apps folder
[image]

The workaround was I have packaged a simple exe along with my UWP app package during first launch of the app the packaged exe will be copied to outside uwp sandbox, from the windows schedule I will execute this copied 'exe' say sample.exe and sample .exe will send a custom windows message to my UWP app.

Answer (score 1):

The work around provided by thunderbird would work only with the Desktop Bridged UWP app. Native UWP app cannot do this way.